# Compatibility of embrac and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, typography, italic, embrac

I'd like to use the `embrac` package to enforce upright parentheses and brackets in emphasized text.  While the `embrac` manual claims the package is compatible with biblatex, all the brackets and parentheses occurring in the book titles of my bibliography remain in italics.  Is there something I am missing here?

Minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[biblatex=true]{embrac}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@InProceedings{gnucon,
  author = {Gary Gnu},
  title = {Gnus I Have Known And Loved},
  booktitle = {Proc. 3rd Workshop [on] Gnuphilia (GNUCON)},
  year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\emph{This (this) is a test. This [this] is a test.} % Works as expected
\nocite{gnucon}
\printbibliography % Parentheses are unexpectedly in italics here
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output of the above example, showing incorrectly italicized brackets and parentheses in the bibliography]

Comment: Actually the compatibility between `embrac` and `biblatex` is very fragile… `embrac` actually disables the replacement of the brackets in `biblatex`s macros for compatibility. The reason for this is that biblatex's titles in the end are something like `\mkbibemph{\macro[option]{title}}` and if those brackets are replaced the macro won't find its optional argument and things go very wrong…

Comment: To see what that means just compile your MWE with `\usepackage[biblatex=false]{embrac}`

Answer (score 3):

`embrac` doesn't work if you hide the text in a macro. So imho the direct input of brackets and parens won't work. But you can use the commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[biblatex=true]{embrac}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
%\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@InProceedings{gnucon,
  author = {Gary Gnu},
  title = {Gnus I Have Known And Loved},
  booktitle = {Proc. 3rd Workshop \mkbibbrackets{on} Gnuphilia \mkbibparens{GNUCON}},
  year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}


\emph{This (this) is a test. This [this] is a test.} % Works as expected
\newcommand\mytext{This (this) is a test. This [this] is a test.}
\emph{\mytext} %doesn't work
\nocite{gnucon}
\printbibliography % Parentheses are unexpectedly in italics here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pity if this is the best solution—the whole point of `embrac` was to avoid manually marking up brackets and parentheses. :(

Comment: You could use a sourcemap so that biber does the replacement.